# Лечение битого сектора на диске в рейде

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid

Есть несколько сбойных секторов на одном из двух дисков, объединенных в raid 1 (зеркало). Рейд софтовый.
Поменять диск прямо сейчас возможности нет.

Хочу попробовать "вылечить" переписав сектор командой:

```
hdparm --write-sector 33333333 /dev/sdb
```

Был просто диск - попробовал бы, а вот что получится при наличии рейда? Ничего плохого не случится? А то еще и сервер совсем не рядом.

Comment: Может быть лучше отключить сбойный диск и подключить его заново -- он и перепишется при этом весь

Comment: @sercxjo более глупого способа избавиться от данных и придумать нельзя - вы предлагаете подвергнуть диск, на котором уже есть бэд полной перезаписи. С диска, который скорее всего ему идентичен.
Вероятность потери рейда в такой ситуации - огромна.

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от рейда, думаю.

Я советую забэкапить всё на рейде и попробовать перезаписать. Но перед перезаписью советую попробовать

```
su -c "fsck -p /dev/sdxX "
```